# Error con Nombre de Columna en Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo un problema con una base de datos en SqlServer 2008, estoy haciendo unos reportes para mostrarlos en un proyecto de Django desde una base de datos en producción, que es usada por otro sistema, tengo la siguiente vista:

```
class DetalleDeuda(ListView):
    model = T090Deudas
    template_name = 'deudas.html'
    context_object_name = 'deudas'    

    @method_decorator(permission_required('deudas.ver_deuda_prescrita',reverse_lazy('usuarios:permiso_denegado')))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.contribuyente = self.kwargs['contribuyente']
        return super(DetalleDeuda, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):        
        context = super(DetalleDeuda, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        contrib = T001Contribuyente.objects.get(c001cod_cont=self.contribuyente)
        context['contribuyente'] = contrib        
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = T090Deudas.objects.filter(c090cod_cont=self.contribuyente)
        return queryset
```

Pero lamentablemente los programadores anteriores nombraron una columna de la tabla T090Deudas, como c090Año, por lo que al mostrar el resultado en mi template me sale el siguiente error:

> Exception Type:   UnicodeDecodeError
>
> Exception Value:    'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)

No puedo cambiar el nombre de la columna, ya que esto significaría alterar el otro sistema que está hecho en Visual Basic y es bastante grande, quisiera saber si es posible hacer algo o simplemente debo hacer la consulta omitiendo esa columna.

Comment: Prueba colocando # encoding=utf8 al inicio de la vista,antes de los imports

Comment: Haciendo referencia al comentario de Javier, creo que la línea correcta es `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Acá te dejo un tema donde muestran como ponerlo y su función: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source

Answer (score 1):

Prueba

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Si bien esto puede responder a la pregunta, pero no sabemos que hacer con este código, podrías explicarnos? [Desde Revisión](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11982)

Answer (score 1):

donde definiste la vista y el modelo correspondiente en python tenes la cabecera Charset, si no es asi prueba agregarla debería solucionar el problema ya que es un error en el interprete:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

ó

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa el atributo **db_column** en la definición del campo en el modelo.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#db-column

Ejemplo:

```
c090year = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column='c090Año')
```